End Grain cutting board
I am gluing up a cutting board blank 24" long, 12" wide and 1.5" high. I intend on cutting it on the 12 " dimension into 1.5 " wide strips, turning those pieces to expose end grain and re-glue. Will I still have a 24" long piece?

If you misalign your strips, then you’d have to trim the board and it will get shorter than 24”. Other than that, I am not sure why you would not get 24”. Am I missing something?

Thanks stanch....you're not missing anything , just me trying to avoid mistakes....thanks for commenting!

It depends on what you mean by 'cutting it on the 12 inch dimension into strips".  I interpret that to mean you want to make a series of cuts across the 12 inch width, with each cut giving a strip that is 1.5 by 1.5 by 12, and leaving a piece that is about 22.5 inches long after the first cut, about 21 inches after the second, etc.
If you do it this way, you'll lose a sawblade's width with each cut, so the first cut will shorten the board from 24 to about 22 3/8 instead of the expected 22 1/2, the second cut will make it 20 3/4 instead of 21.
In the end, you won't get the expected 16 pieces 1.5 by 1.5, but instead 14 pieces that size and one narrower one.  The board will then end up 21 inches long (14 x 1.5) assuming you only use the full width strips.  You can avoid this by making the strips 1.25 or 1.375 inches wide, producing a slightly thinner board.
However, if "cutting it on the 12 inch dimension" means cutting it the other way, then the length will remain at 24 inches.

Good Answer to what is fundamentally a bad Question, bravo.
